# Как переопределить действия middle button в firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

в ff на middle button висит действие `back`

как его заменить свой функцией?

```
$('.myDiv').bind('mousedown', function(e) {

    if(e.which == 2) {
        /* мой код */
        return;
    }

})
```

так работает только в Chrome

Comment: Back? о_О Что-то тут не то.

Comment: Что за middle button?